# Python: Zipping multiple lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

Ok, so I have 6 lists taken from a csv file that I want to create a dictionary from, with one list being the key value and the other 5 each containing a value attached to that key.  I them am deleting certain rows if their keys match a value in a 7th list (c6).  Any help is appreciated, write now I'm stuck getting the lists to populate from the correct column of the csv.  I also have a messy amount of readers since they can only be looped through once.

```
with open (r'filea', 'r', newline='') as f:
    tread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    aread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    bread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    cread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    dread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    eread=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    tlist= []
    alist= []
    blist= []
    clist= []
    dlist= []
    elist= []

    for row in tread:
        tlist.append(row[0])

    for row in aread:
        alist.append(row[1])
        print (alist)
    for row in bread:
        blist.append(row[2])
        print (blist)
    for row in cread:
        clist.append(row[3])
    for row in dread:
        dlist.append(row[4])
    for row in eread:
        elist.append(row[5])

    fulldict = dict(zip(tlist, [alist, blist, clist, dlist, elist]))
    print (fulldict)
    for key in c6:
        if key  in fulldict:
            del fulldict[key]
        if key not in fulldict:
            pass
    with open (r'fileb', 'w', newline='') as g:
        wrt=csv.writer(g)
        for row in fulldict.items():
            wrt.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a dict if all you're doing is writing its elements out as a list?  I suspect there are much simpler ways to accomplish your goal.  Can you just show what your input CSV looks like and what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I'm trying to remove elements attached to one value in the dictionary prior to writing it.

Comment: I want the export csv to look exactly like the input just with certain rows removed.  Its 6 columns by ~400 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open (r'filea', 'r', newline='') as f:

    data = {}
    exclude = set()

    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
        data[row[0]] = row[1:6]
        exclude.add(row[6])

    for key in exclude:
        if key in data:
            del data[key]

    with open (r'fileb', 'w', newline='') as g:
        wrt=csv.writer(g)
        # do the writing
```

I ended with `do the writing` because I don't know what you want to write. Your writing code is wrong, as `items()` of dict is a list of `(key, value)` tuples.

Comment: Thank you this is along the lines of what I need.